# Why is member function call "ambiguous"?

Tags: c++, mutators

Why is my overloaded member function only "ambiguous" as a char and not an int and string?

I'm trying to create a one-code path for my Char class by funneling code through an overloaded equals() function. It works fine when I use equals as an int and string but is ambiguous as a char.

```
class Char
{
private:
    char cData;
    int iData;
    string sData;
public:
    //Mutators:
    void equals(char c);
    void equals(int c);
    void equals(string c);

    //Constructors:
    Char(char c);
    Char(int c);
    Char(string c);
};

void Char::equals(char c)
{
    cData = c;
}

void Char::equals(int c)
{
    iData = c;
}

void Char::equals(string c)
{
    sData = c;
}

Char::Char(char c)
{
    this->equals(c); //Call to member function 'equals' is ambiguous
}

Char::Char(int c)
{
    this->equals(c);
}

Char::Char(string c)
{
    this->equals(c);
}
```

The error only happens for char, which is confusing since string works fine. I expected it to work for all of them since that's been the case so far.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Should I cut down on the code provided?

Comment: You should post the minimum amount of code that one can use to reproduce the error.

Comment: What they're saying is you need to provide more code. Like... could you provide us with enough code that we can get the same compile error that you're seeing? That'll help us figure out the problem

Comment: It's minimal and repoducable now.

Comment: the updated code compiles without errors. Could you add the other functions back in?

Comment: Apologies, the functions are back in.

Comment: Your code compiles fine in both GCC and Clang. What compiler are you using, and what version?

Comment: For there to be an ambiguous function call, you actually have to use the functions. Can you show us the function call that is ambiguous (e.g., a `main` method) and also the actual error output?

Comment: On a side note, unless there is some reason not to (constraints on a class assignment, for instance), I would suggest using `std::variant` to store your members in order to avoid confusion about which one is currently held.

Comment: your code compiles fine. check here: https://godbolt.org/z/lCXaL7 The problem is your code may not work as you expect. this call `c.equals(150 - 'a');` you expect a char but you will get an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ambiguous because if you do

```
Char c(42);
```

The compiler does not know whether it should call the `char` or `int` constructor. Both are an equally good match.

The same goes for `equals(123);`. Again, both the `char` and `int` overloads match and the compiler cannot tell which one you intend to call.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single `equal` method to accept a `char` or an `int`. like

```
void euqals(unsigned int c_i);
```